# How to set RESPONSE Headers globally using J2EE container (Websphere)

Tags: java, http-headers, websphere

Is there a way, at the web server level (web.xml) to set headers for all transactions?  Specifically, I would like to do this:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
```

at the application level.  I seem to recall that headers could be set in the Web.xml.  Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement a `javax.servlet.Filter`, write appropriate logic in `doFilter()` method and finally map it in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of `/*`.

By the way, the 'magic' set which works in all known browsers and proxies are those:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```