# How to make compress file like *.css.gz work well in browser

Tags: javascript, css, maven, compression, gzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make maven serve files like css.gz and js.gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668970/make-maven-serve-files-like-css-gz-and-js-gz)

When I use file like style.css and run in browser, it works well but when I compress the file become style.css.gz and run it again, it not works at all. 
So, I just want to ask how to configure so the compressed file like that can be work well in browser???

In this case I'm working with a Java EE project and using Apache Maven.

Comment: Check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894779/gzip-compression-for-jsf-stuff. And this question is more or less a duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668970/make-maven-serve-file-like-css-gz-and-js-gz

Answer (score 4):

You need to add special response header which will tell your browser that your content is encoded as gzip, for example in C#:

```
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
```

In this case browser will automatically decompress your file.

Comment: I know that I can use that way, I'm can do it in PHP project
but the problem that I want to know about the step to configure in J2EE project, because I'm new in here...
Thanks...

Comment: [How to set RESPONSE Headers globally using J2EE container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676953/how-to-set-response-headers-globally-using-j2ee-container-websphere)
or by config [responseheaderfilter](http://code.google.com/p/responseheaderfilter/)